# After the installation of the Java JDK, why do I need to install the JRE

Tags: java, installation

The JDK contains the JRE, but even after installing the JDK and setting JAVA_HOME, whenever I test Java using webstart or the [Java test page](http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp), it says that Java is not installed. Do I need to install the JRE?

Comment: as far as i know, the `JAVA_HOME` variable is just for the jdk. Did the JDK-Installer correctly include the JRE in the `PATH` variable?

Comment: You need to enable the "install public JRE" during JDK installation to install the browser plugin which is required for WebStart

Comment: the path is correct ,but i am using 64 bit jdk,is it effect path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ,Thanks for a_horse_with_no_name I found that , the reason is because  JRE is not just by Oracle, there could be vendor JREs like Weblogic uses JRockit JRE.
And to separate development environment JRE from run time execution oracle installation is not getting last installation JRE as home JRE and public . Plus The public JRE installation uses Registry entries; to run java base apps the private one doesn’t.

In development face also user may use stack trace or dump memory isolated from public one.
The class version exception also may occur in update public JRE when jdk is newer.
Either we can set private from command line during installation such

```
 jdk.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature,PublicjreFeature"
```

Earlier version may has public installation shows after installing JDK.

Answer (score 5):

In order for java to work in a browser, you need the java browser plugin, which does not come with the JDK.